# an array of type Interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mean-stack

I have an interface as follows:

```js
export interface testInterface
{

    value1: string;
    value2:string[];
    SubValue:[{}]

}
```

and I am filling an array of type *testInterface*--which is bind to a dropdown list. everything works fine. I would like the dropdown  list have says " Pick One" as its first object. so I did the following:

```js
default:testInterface[]=[] //==> since the bind array needs to be an array.

this.default.value1="----Please Select the Sub-Industry---";
this.default.value2=[];
this.default.SubValue=[];
```

I got this error on the line of the **subValue**:
 Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[{ value1: string; value2: string[]; value3...'.
  Property '0' is missing in type 'undefined[]'.

why i cannot say dropdownArray[0].push=this.default???

Could someone explain me why is it? the issue may sound obvious to some of you, but I am newbie!

ACCTUAL CODE:

```html
//how I fille the binded array:

 subsDataofSelectedSector:ISubIndustry[]=[];

        if (response.SubIndustries.length > 0) {
          for (i = 0; i < response.SubIndustries.length; i++) {
            this.subsDataofSelectedSector.push(response.SubIndustries[i]);
          }
        }
        
//the interface

export interface ISubIndustry
{

    IndustrySector: string;
    isSelected: string;
    dataSubjectCategories:string[];
    dataTypeCategories:string[];
    SubIndustries:[{}]

}

//the default array

this.defaultSub.dataSubjectCategories =[];
this.defaultSub.dataTypeCategories=[];
this.defaultSub.IndustrySector="----Please Select the Sub-Industry---";
this.defaultSub.SubIndustries=[];
this.defaultSub.isSelected="true";

// i would like to to do the following and add the rest after index 0

 this.subsDataofSelectedSector[0].push(this.defaultSub)
```

heer is a part of JSON file I have to inject to the array.

```js
{
    "IndustrySector":"Other Services Activities",
    "isSelected": "false",
    "dataSubjectCategories":["DS.Employees","DS.Collaborators","DS.Legal Person","DS.Natural Person"],
    "dataTypeCategories":["Personal Data"],
    "SubIndustries": [
      {
        "IndustrySector":"Activities of Membership Organisations",
        "isSelected": "false",
        "dataSubjectCategories":[],
        "dataTypeCategories":[],
        "SubIndustries": [
          {
            "IndustrySector":"Activities of Other Membership Organisations",
            "isSelected": "false",
            "dataSubjectCategories":[],
            "dataTypeCategories":[],
            "SubIndustries":[
              {
```

as you see, one can have some subvalue and each sub can also have sub. so i defined it as array of object

Comment: Can you show complete component code?

Comment: The error you are getting suggests that ` SubValue:[{}]` has something more between the `{}` could you post the actual code please ?

Comment: i did, please have a look

Comment: In your interface, why don't you define your `SubValue` as an array instead of an array of object ?

Comment: since the variable of this type gonna be filled with a JSON file, which has an array of subValue

Comment: Your code is still far from a minimal working sample that demonstrates the error .. I guess this ` SubValue:[{}]` should probably be  `SubValue:{}[]` since you probably want an array not a tuple.. but it's hard to say from your post

Comment: I have aded te json file, may clear things a bit

Answer (score 0):

Because you are pushing into the object, not array.

Furthermore SubValue is an array of objects not an array this.default.SubValue=[];

```
this.default.SubValue.push({});
```

When you create the interface its proterties must match.

In other words if your case (as long as all properties are required, you can make them optional with "a question mark")

So when you initializing default obejcts all of its properties must match with interface, ex

```
default.push({
  value1 = "----Please Select the Sub-Industry---",
  value2 = [],
  SubValue = [{}]
})
```

Or make optional properties and use your way

```
export interface testInterface
{

    value1: string;
    value2?:string[];
    SubValue?:[{}]

}
```

To sum it up... In your case the problem lies in this line this.default.value1

1. default must be a value
2. its properties must match defining in interface ones

Comment: this says:  Type 'undefined[]' is not assignable to type '[{}]'

Comment: changed the answer. have a look

Answer (score 0):

default.SubValue is of type array of Object i.e [Object, Object, Object...] and you are assigning the array of undefined to the value i.e [undefined, undefined], thus typescript is giving the error that both types are not the same. You have to specify that it is of type object to clear this error.

this.default.value1="----Please Select the Sub-Industry---";

this.default.value2=[];

this.default.SubValue=[ { } ];

Hope this helps :)